# PL/SQL select into a nested array

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to select values from my table and stock them into an array to manipulate them. this is what i have done.

```
DECLARE 
   TYPE student IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
   s student := student();
   n number := 1;

BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT name from HR.STUDENT) loop
   s(n) := i.name;
   n := n + 1;
   end loop;

end;
```

when i do this i get this error in SQL Developer

> An in-limit subscript was greater than the count of a varray
>              or too large for a nested table.

So i'm asking is this the right way to get a my table values into the student Type? any hints ?

i'm new to PL/SQL so i maybe saying wrong things. correct me when i do so. Thank you.

Comment: How are you manipulating the results, and what are you going to do with them once you've got them? It could be that you'll be better off doing everything in a single sql statement, rather than looping through an array and then updating/inserting each row one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any easier way to accomplish this would be:

```
SELECT name
BULK COLLECT INTO s
FROM   HR.STUDENT;
```

With no need for the loop at all.

The reason the error occurs (I think) is that you are trying to access and index of the table which is not yet available. I believe you need to manually call extend prior to the access, which would then make the next index of the array available e.g.

```
FOR i IN (SELECT name from HR.STUDENT)
LOOP 
  s.extend;
  s(n) := i.name;
  n := n+1;
END LOOP;
```

Also I believe you need to have s students := students(); - you seem to be missing a colon.

Comment: Good stuff. I have since updated my answer with an alternative solution and an explanation on why you were receiving the error.